How to solve circuit error in qiskit
I am trying to run the grover's algorithm in qiskit using Google collab.
!pip  install qiskit

!pip install qiskit-aer

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import Aer

# Define the black box function


def oracle(circuit, register, marked_state):
  for i in range(len(marked_state)):
    if marked_state[i] == '1':
      circuit.x(register[i])
  circuit.cz(register[0], register[1])
  for i in range(len(marked_state)):
    if marked_state[i] == '1':
      circuit.x(register[i])

# Define the Grover diffusion operator


def grover_diffusion(circuit, register):
  circuit.h(register)
  circuit.x(register)
  circuit.h(register[1])
  circuit.cx(register[0], register[1])
  circuit.h(register[1])
  circuit.x(register)
  circuit.h(register)

# Define the Grover algorithm


def grover(marked_state):

  # Initialize a quantum register
    # of n qubits
  n = len(marked_state)
  cr = ClassicalRegister(n)
  circuit = QuantumCircuit(QuantumRegister(n), cr)
  print(QuantumRegister(n))

    # Apply the Hadamard gate
    # to each qubit
  circuit.h(QuantumRegister(n))

    # Repeat the following procedure
    # O(sqrt(2 ^ n)) times
  num_iterations = int(round((2 ** n) ** 0.5))
  for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Apply the black box function f
        # to the current state to mark
        # the solution
    oracle(circuit, QuantumRegister(n), marked_state)

        # Apply the Grover diffusion
        # operator to amplify the amplitude
        # of the marked solution
    grover_diffusion(circuit, QuantumRegister(n))

    # Measure the state to obtain
    # a solution x
    circuit.measure(QuantumRegister(n), cr)

# Run the circuit on a simulator

    backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    job = transpile(circuit, backend)
    result = job.result()
    counts = result.get_counts()
    x = list(counts.keys())[0]

  return x

# Test the Grover algorithm
marked_state = '101'
result = grover(marked_state)
print(f"The marked state is {result}")

I printed out the output for
QuantumRegister(n)

and got this as the output.

QuantumRegister(3, 'q10')

And following is the error in detail:
CircuitError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-84fcb091756e> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # Test the Grover algorithm
      2 marked_state = '101'
----> 3 result = grover(marked_state)
      4 print(f"The marked state is {result}")

<ipython-input-29-627ce7879714> in grover(marked_state)
     13         # Apply the Hadamard gate
     14         # to each qubit
---> 15   circuit.h(QuantumRegister(n))
     16 
     17         # Repeat the following procedure

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in h(self, qubit)
   4509             A handle to the instructions created.
   4510         """
-> 4511         return self._append_standard_gate(StandardGate.HGate, [qubit], ())
   4512 
   4513     def ch(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in _append_standard_gate(self, op, qargs, params, label)
   2459             params = []
   2460 
-> 2461         expanded_qargs = [self._qbit_argument_conversion(qarg) for qarg in qargs or []]
   2462         for param in params:
   2463             Gate.validate_parameter(op, param)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   2459             params = []
   2460 
-> 2461         expanded_qargs = [self._qbit_argument_conversion(qarg) for qarg in qargs or []]
   2462         for param in params:
   2463             Gate.validate_parameter(op, param)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in _qbit_argument_conversion(self, qubit_representation)
   2408             The resolved instances of the qubits.
   2409         """
-> 2410         return _bit_argument_conversion(
   2411             qubit_representation, self.qubits, self._qubit_indices, Qubit
   2412         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in _bit_argument_conversion(specifier, bit_sequence, bit_set, type_)
   6766         return bit_sequence[specifier]
   6767     try:
-> 6768         return [
   6769             _bit_argument_conversion_scalar(index, bit_sequence, bit_set, type_)
   6770             for index in specifier

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   6767     try:
   6768         return [
-> 6769             _bit_argument_conversion_scalar(index, bit_sequence, bit_set, type_)
   6770             for index in specifier
   6771         ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in _bit_argument_conversion_scalar(specifier, bit_sequence, bit_set, type_)
   6783         if specifier in bit_set:
   6784             return specifier
-> 6785         raise CircuitError(f"Bit '{specifier}' is not in the circuit.")
   6786     if isinstance(specifier, (int, np.integer)):
   6787         try:

CircuitError: "Bit 'Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q11'), 0)' is not in the circuit."

The main issue is that I still can't quite figure out the error. How do I solve this error? Even some guidance is appreciated.
I tried printing the output of QuantumRegister(n) to find some connection with the error, but couldn't make any useful one. I also tried to understand the q11 in the QuantumRegister and 0 inside the qubit in CircuitError: "Bit 'Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q11'), 0)' is not in the circuit.". But again failed to do do so. So i'd also appreciate to know if there's any connection between this q11 and the q10 in the output of QuantumRegister(n).

I found a few minor typos. Just instantiate a quantum register once and use it instead of instantiating one each time otherwise you get the stated error. I put some comments in your code.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import Aer

# Define the black box function


def oracle(circuit, register, marked_state):
  for i in range(len(marked_state)):
    if marked_state[i] == '1':
      circuit.x(register[i])
  circuit.cz(register[0], register[1])
  for i in range(len(marked_state)):
    if marked_state[i] == '1':
      circuit.x(register[i])

# Define the Grover diffusion operator


def grover_diffusion(circuit, register):
  circuit.h(register)
  circuit.x(register)
  circuit.h(register[1])
  circuit.cx(register[0], register[1])
  circuit.h(register[1])
  circuit.x(register)
  circuit.h(register)

# Define the Grover algorithm


def grover(marked_state):

  # Initialize a quantum register
    # of n qubits
  n = len(marked_state)
  cr = ClassicalRegister(n)
  qr = QuantumRegister(n) # instantiate here only once
  circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
  print(qr)

    # Apply the Hadamard gate
    # to each qubit
  circuit.h(qr)

    # Repeat the following procedure
    # O(sqrt(2 ^ n)) times
  num_iterations = int(round((2 ** n) ** 0.5))
  for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Apply the black box function f
        # to the current state to mark
        # the solution
    oracle(circuit, qr, marked_state)

        # Apply the Grover diffusion
        # operator to amplify the amplitude
        # of the marked solution
    grover_diffusion(circuit, qr)

    # Measure the state to obtain
    # a solution x
    circuit.measure(qr, cr)

# Run the circuit on a simulator

    backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    job = backend.run(circuit)
    #job = transpile(circuit, backend)
    result = job.result()
    counts = result.results[0].data.counts  #result.get_counts()
    x = list(counts.keys())[0]

  return x

# Test the Grover algorithm
marked_state = '101'
result = grover(marked_state)
print(f"The marked state is {result}")

result :
QuantumRegister(3, 'q7')
The marked state is 0x3

Thank you so much! It worked and I've been trying to solve it for days. Just goes to show how much I need to learn more.
